# Could anyone explain the hidden prop description?

Tags: material-ui

on this page: https://material-ui.com/api/hidden/ the description for the `mdUp` prop on this component states: "If true, screens this size and up will be hidden"

That means absolutely nothing to me.  What screens? What size? Can anyone explain?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The breakpoints are theme-specific and you can check the [default theme here](https://material-ui.com/customization/default-theme/) under `breakpoints.values`

```
<Hidden mdUp>
  I will not be visible on width 960 and above
</Hidden>
```

Comment: thank you.  now it makes sense.  wish the docs were clearer about it